# LWUIT calendar: highlight days to have different styles. How to achieve it?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to use LWUIT 1.5 `Calendar` class to show different background color to certain days to show that those dates have some event scheduled. I tried overriding the `createDay()` method of the `Calendar` class but it does not work. What am I doing wrong in this? What do i write so that the `createDay()` method below applies the bgColor correctly?

I also want to add `Command` to those `Buttons` to take the user to event details screen. Can I just add `commandListener` to the `Button`?

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar() {

        protected Button createDay() {
            Button day = new Button();
            day.getStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
            day.setAlignment(LEFT);
            day.setUIID("CalendarDay");
            day.setEndsWith3Points(false);
            day.setTickerEnabled(false);
            return day;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many UIID related to the Calendar days. They are `CalendarDay` `CalendarNavigation` `CalendarSelectedDay`. Try to configurate this UIIDs' (Unselected, Selected, Pressed and Disabled) styles when you build your theme.

Comment: I want to apply theme to only those days for which an event is available. E.g. on Mach 16th, there is a soccer game in my town so that day of the month will be shown with red bg.

Comment: ok, so when you have a marked day, put to it another UIID and build another style in the Resource editor